# Unable to find where my database file and connection string is located?

Tags: c#, sql-server, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

i downloaded a demo application from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Authorization-based-aa2c0185/view/SourceCode

I run it on my Visual Studio and all worked fine. There is a database `ASPNETDB.MDF` in its `App_Data` folder which is used to store the user information or retrieve information for login purpose.

Now what I want is to change this database with another database in my SQL Server.

For that there can be two ways :

- Locate the connection string etc. for `ASPNETDB` and change them with my own database.
- or add this `ASPNETDB` file to SQL Server by attaching. But its showing error while attaching it.

Also if I exclude `App_Data` folder from project...Then even it works...

Where can find connection string for DB? I want to change the DB with mine own ?

Please Help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's using default connection string from machine.config:

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated  Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `Web.debug.config` file. There you will find comments noting how to wire up your config file. This will use config transforms so that when you build in debug mode, it will change your config file to override the machine defaults (which is what it is currently using). Just follow the comments and you should be good :)